# Firebase: How to delete collection within a collection?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a cart page in Flutter. For deleting a particular item in the cart, I am facing an issue. I want to delete a document inside collection "items" which is inside collection "myOrders"

myOrders => docID => items => **docID(to be deleted)**

This is the code I tried,

```
    Future deleteData(BuildContext context)
    {
      final user = Provider.of<Userr?>(context,listen: false);
      CollectionReference _collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myOrders');
      return _collectionRef.doc(user?.uid).collection('items').doc().delete();
    }
```

[image: Firebase Sample Image]

I need to know why it is not getting deleted and what change I need to do in the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you're calling `.doc()` to create the following reference, without passing anything as an argument:

```
 _collectionRef.doc(user?.uid).collection('items').doc()
//
```

It literally means that you're always generating a new **unique** document ID. When you call `delete()`, you're trying to delete a document that actually doesn't exist, hence that behavior.

If you want to create a reference that points to a particular item (document) inside the `items` sub-collection, then you have to pass the document ID of that item, which already exists in the database, and **not** generate a brand new one. So to solve this, get the document ID of the item you want to delete and pass it to the `.doc()` function like this:

```
 _collectionRef.doc(user?.uid).collection('items').doc('itemDocId')
//
```

Comment: How to fetch the exact itemDocId from the firebase that I want to delete?

Comment: A possible solution would be to store the document ID as a field inside each item document. When you display the items, when you click on a particular item, you can read that property and pass it to the `doc()` function. In this way, you'll be able to delete the item that was clicked, right?

Comment: How to store the exact document id into its field! When I tried to add while creating it generates a random Id and it gets stored

Comment: @AswinB easiest way is to generate your own ids when you're creating the objects and store them as a field on your object. Another way would be `onCreate` hooks that save the auto generated ids when a new object is created. But you should be receiving them already with any query you're making. When you are parsing your response, the id is on the document reference object.

Comment: @ColdLogic Thanks for commenting. Yep Aswin, that's a solution you can go ahead with. Give it a try, and tell us if it works.

Comment: Hey Thanks Alex and ColdLogic!! I added a docid field to the collection and done the deletion part by deleting the document which matches the ID !!

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the id of the document to be deleted.
so modify your code as

```
Future deleteData(BuildContext context)
{
  final user = Provider.of<Userr?>(context,listen: false);
  CollectionReference _collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myOrders');
  return _collectionRef.doc(user?.uid).collection('items').doc('document_id_to_be_deleted').delete();
}
```

Comment: But how to fetch the document id to be deleted?

Comment: you must be getting id in the cart page bcz you're showing data from firebase.